# Why do I see $\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}=\sin\theta$ in integration solutions?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to integrate:

$$\int x \sqrt{-x^2+6x-8} \ dx $$

After a substitution $x-3=\cos \ \theta$, I got that the integral written above is equal to:

$$\int (\cos \ \theta +3)\sqrt{\sin^2 \ \theta}(-\sin \ \theta \ d\theta)$$

I see often in problem solutions on the internet, that you write $\sin \ \theta$ instead of the square root  above. After that step, integration is something I know how to do.

My question is stated in the question topic. Why can we say that the square root is equivalent to $\sin$? Can't the $\sin$ be negative?

Could you provide me with an explanation? Cheers.

Comment: I would say $\sqrt{sin^2 \theta}=|sin \theta|$

Comment: This is obviously always true, but that's not what I wanted to know :) See the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because to be able to go back to the original variable, you have to use a *bijective* change of variable. Setting $x-3=\cos\theta$ does not define a bijection. It does if you restrict $\theta$ to the interval $[0,\pi]$, for instance, i.e. if you set $\theta=\arccos(x-3)$.

Comment: Oh, so in that case it's just because there's an interval on which cos gets all the necessary values and sin is only nonnegative? I think I get it!

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: It's perfecly correct. Had you chosen  the interval $[\pi,2\pi]$, you'd have had to to write $-\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\ge0$  for real $a$

Actual  substitution  $\theta=\arccos(x-3)$

The principal value of $\theta$ lies in $[0,\pi]$

$\implies\sin\theta\ge0$

But you are free to choose other ranges of $\theta$  like $[\pi,2\pi]$ where $\sin\theta\le0$

If you substitute back the value of $\theta,$ you will reach at the same result.

Please verify

Comment: This illustates that it's dangerous not to write bounds !

Comment: What does the third line mean? What do you mean by *principal value*?

Comment: @Iwanttomakegames, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values